# Sending GPS data to a web portal or my laptop

Tags: java, android, gps, maps

I am new to Android programming. As a part of my College Final Year Project, I decided to make a **mobile tracking** application. This will be using the Google Maps API.

It will be updating the device's location and sending it to a web portal. Can someone please tell me what should I do in order to send the GPS co-ordinates to the portal? Also, is it possible to send these co-ordinates to my laptop?

Comment: so far.. the device is updating the location.. 

but i want it to update it and send it to a web portal or maybe my laptop..

Comment: usually people use web servers and services for that. can be a simple php scripts that puts values in a mysql table

Comment: thanks.. i figured that out..

but how is the device supposed to do that.. 

what package should i use on eclipse to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should create an Http End point which accepts an Http POST request.
Create this request using HttpURLConnection class in your android project.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Make sure you make this call in a non UI thread.(hint use AsyncTask or your own thread)

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
       urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
       urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

       OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
           urlConnection.getOutputStream());
       writeStream(out);

      InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
      readStream(in);
   }finally {
      urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank You sir..

will try it out.. :)